# Use an anonymous function when setting the return value for a getter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin when you create a getter/setter pair, you typically set the getter using inline code. But I am wondering if it is possible to replace the inline code with an anonymous function:

```
var UserSettings: UserSettings?
    get() = getUserSettings() // Replace this with an anonymous function?
    set(value) {
        putPref(USER_SETTINGS, Json.stringify(UserSettings.serializer(), value!!))
    }

private fun getUserSettings(): UserSettings? {
    val info = getPref(KEY_USER_SETTINGS)
    return Json.parse(UserSettings.serializer(), info!!)
}
```

Can the getUserSettings() be replaced with an anonymous function? In the code above I have a separate function getUserSettings that I would like to place right after the get() =

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just have a look at [getters and setters - backing properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties), where there is (the first and only example), mentioning `get() {` instead of `get() =`. Your sample would then look as follows:

```
var UserSettings: UserSettings?
  get() { 
    val info = getPref(KEY_USER_SETTINGS)
    return Json.parse(UserSettings.serializer(), info!!)
  }
  set(value) {
    putPref(USER_SETTINGS, Json.stringify(UserSettings.serializer(), value!!))
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this what he meant.. I mean it's so obvious, and it takes 3 seconds to try

Comment: @TimCastelijns while I agree that it's rather obvious... which anonymous function could be meant otherwise?

Comment: @AndroidDev then I wonder why you didn't add that to your question... based on the link above I derived the answer... and at least for some other basic types it already worked as expected ;-)

Comment: @AndroidDev calm down... not everyone has the luxury to test everything immediately with full system support... my answer is based on this code here: `public val table: Map<String, Int> get() { if (_table == null) { _table = HashMap() } return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread") }`, which is shown on the linked page... I can only advise you to add that variant to your question as well with the appropriate error message... and let me just be clear... I just linked that part, because that's the first (and only) example on the page with `get() {` instead of `get() =`

Comment: @AndroidDev *It clearly is not supported* the docs cover it so clearly it is, or at least should be, supported. If you have found that is not the case, you should include more details in your question. Excuse me for assuming you didn't try, but you have a habit of asking low effort questions and this seemed like another. Roland's answer covers the question as it is. You asked how to do it and he answered it with docs to back it up. You blame him for his answer being wrong while really, the fault lies in the question.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know this is what you asking for but it might be helpful

```
var v: Int? = null
    get() = run {
        return field
    }
    set(value) = run {
        field = value
    }
```

in this case getter must be equel to Int? and setter allways must be equel to Unit. so in the run we return that types

Comment: while this works, I can't really recommend using the single-expression-style for this... just stick to the default `get() { ... }` or `set(value) { field = ... }`... you even spare some characters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of @Roland is valid.

Be aware that maintaining the `=` before the anonymous function the compiler returns an error as you are describing.

Can you double check that you are NOT writing something like this?

```
var UserSettings: UserSettings?
  get() = { ... }
```

And that you are writing:

```
var UserSettings: UserSettings?
  get() { ... }
```